# Python - How to save the *exact* video stream that my USB cam is streaming live?

Tags: python, opencv, video, save, video-streaming

I am using OpenCV 4.5.0 to stream a video from a USB webcam using the VideoCapture method of OpenCV. Here is the snippet of how I am reading the frames, processing them and then writing them to a file.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
dev_id = 0
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(dev_id, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'FMP4')
vpath = 'test.mp4'
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(vpath, fourcc, 30, (640,480), isColor=True)

if stream.isOpened():
    rval, frame = stream.read()
else:
    print('Could not open the stream for reading')
if not writer.isOpened():
    print('Could not open the file for writing')

i = 0
while rval:
    i += 1
    with open('frame_{}.pkl'.format(i),'wb') as fout:
        np.save(fout, frame)

    writer.write(frame)

    rval, frame = stream.read()
    key = cv2.waitkey(1)
    if key == 27: # ESC
        break 

writer.release()
```

My goal is to then read the video file that was written above and reproduce the exact same frames that I got during the live stream. I have not been able to find a way to write the live video stream to a file such that the frame extracted from the written video file matches exactly with the frame stored in the numpy array. In addition to FMP4 as the FourCC, I tried with MJPG, MP4V, XVID, LAGS, H264, MPG4. No luck so far. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I am reading the video and comparing the frames:

```
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(vpath)
if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame_read = vc.read()
else:
    print('Could not read video from the file')

j = 0
while rval:
    j += 1
    with open('frame_{}.pkl'.format(j),'rb') as fin:
        frame_orig = np.load(fin)
    if np.array_equal(frame_read, frame_orig):
        print('same')
    else:
        print('different')

    rval, frame_read = vc.read()
```

I have also tested if this is simply the indexing mismatch between the video writer and the video reader. It is not. This really looks like the difference caused by the codec used to write the frame to a file. Is there no codec which writes the same exact frame that is emitted by VideoCapture.read()?

Comment: LAGS is a lossless codec. if you tried that and did *not* get the exact same data back, you did something else wrong. in any case, use the right library for the right job. ffmpeg would be a good idea. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for encoding videos. and you need to understand that there is very little "raw" here. cameras might emit YUV. OpenCV (video backend) converts that to RGB/BGR when reading... and the video backend converts that back to YUV for during encode (most codecs work with YUV, not RGB).

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz. Actually the end goal here is related to Computer Vision only; being able to reproduce the results is critical for my development task. 
Your comments about nothing being "raw" here is quite insightful. in that case, I guess what I am looking for is to be able to reproduce the frame that OpenCV emitted (and hence my downstream algo took as an input). One solution I see is writing each frame as BMP using FFMPEG, but even that is not working so far. Do you spot anything else wrong with the code?

Comment: edited the original post to clarify the goal

Comment: look at `PyAV`, a true and proper wrapper around ffmpeg's libraries. full control over your interaction with FFMPEG. the library has some basic examples you should be able to copy and modify. that way you can work around OpenCV's convenient but meddlesome YUV/RGB/YUV conversion.

Comment: PyAV might also work for video capture (haven't tried it... ffmpeg certainly can do it), but OpenCV has a `CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB` flag/propery on VideoCapture objects. disable it to get the untouched data straight from the camera... that data might turn out to be MJPEG, so be warned. when you deal with camera data, you want to learn about "presentation timestamps" (PTS). they're the truth behind "FPS" in almost every video file format anyway. at least one PyAV example shows how to write video with non-trivial PTSes.